# How to verify the number of elements that the element is displayed on Selenium with Java + TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I've taken elements with page factory like the code below :

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//tr[@id='product-2']")
private WebElement cartPageProduct1;

@FindBy (xpath = "//tr[@id='product-3']")
private WebElement cartPageProduct2;
```

The method I use to display the element is:

```
public void viewCartVerifyCart() {
    ArrayList<WebElement> items = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    items.add(cartPageProduct1);
    items.add(cartPageProduct2);
    
    for(WebElement element : items) {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, element.isDisplayed());
    }
}
```

Is the method I'm using correct to verify that the element is showing like the code above? if wrong please help me to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing/facing any error?

Comment: I'd rather verify the item name, it's description, value/price etc. in the cart using automation. Cause `isDisplayed` is just to make sure `//tr[@id='product-2']` is present in HTMLDOM or not.

Comment: Why not get all matching elements by XPath already in a list rather than build the list on your own? You can do something like this `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id, 'product-')]"));`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "_verify the number of elements_"? Are you implying getting a count of how many `element.isDisplayed()` return `true`?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium no, i think this logical error

Comment: @cruisepandey hmmm nice idea

Comment: @hfontanez thanks for your tips i'll try, "verify the number of elements" is i want to verify that the elements in the cart are showing, sorry for my english, i do my best.